# how to redirect network traffic in windows 8 to burp suite?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, proxy, iphone

I have googled for this days and days. I have tried a lot of things but unfortunately did not succeed with any of them.
I have burp suite on my laptop running and listening to port 8080 on 127.0.0.1 as localhost, in order to intercept request from my iPhone I created Adhoc network which has ip addresses like this 192.168.137.xx.
my Iphone did connect to the internet via the Adhoc network but I could not intercept any HTTP request in burp suite, I don't know what to do with this, I am totally frustrated.
in my iphone network settings I defined proxy server which has the ip of my laptop running the burp suite which is 10.0.0.3 and the port 8080 but nothing is intercepted by burp what do I miss here?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You defined the proxy server as the IP of your laptop `10.0.0.3` port `8080`, but the burp suite is not listening on `10.0.0.3:8080`, at least according to your post, it is listening on `127.0.0.1:8080`.  You need to change this to listen for traffic on your physical network interface as it is set to listen for traffic on your loopback interface.

Comment: 10.0.0.3 is equal to 127.0.0.1 the loopback is pointing to the ip 10.0.0.3

Comment: moreover changing the listening to all interfaces to the same port 8080 also did not solve the problem!!

Comment: @flashDisk IP addresses in the 127/8 range are unlike *any* other IP address. They are *never* reachable from outside the PC. They are most certainly *not* equivalent to any other IP address.

Comment: I know they are not reachable from the outside, but who said that I did that? 127.0.0.1 is defined in the burp suite on my laptop not from outside

Comment: @flashDisk What he means from outside is an outside device, not outside the network .  The 127.0.0.1 address on the laptop will never be accessible to any other device except for the laptop.  Have you ever heard of a loopback address before?  Your proxy is only listening for traffic from your laptop if it is configured to listen on 127.0.0.1.  Configure it to all or 10.0.0.3, and if it still does not work, check firewall settings for port blockage, and confirm there is network connectivity between your laptop and phone (ping, etc).

Comment: @528fb there is connectivity between them, I changed the burp setttings to listen to all interfaces on the port 8080 but nothing was intercepted! ,

Comment: @flashDisk Check firewall/security programs on the laptop to make sure that port is not getting blocked.  How did you verify connectivity between the laptop and phone?

Comment: @528fb ping between the ip of the iphone on the adhoc network from my laptop, which port is getting blocked here?!

Comment: @flashDisk Is your phone able to ping 10.0.0.3?  I think you lack a fundamental understanding of some basic concepts to be doing what you are trying to do.  I would study up on some basic networking and server/client relationships.

Comment: yes, my phone can ping my laptop.